# Are there non-compact, non-smoothable manifolds?

Tags: smooth-structures, smoothing-theory, gt.geometric-topology, at.algebraic-topology

There do exist manifolds which do not admit any smooth structure at all. But the only examples I've heard of are all compact.

> Are there any non-compact, non-smoothable manifolds?

Comment: Stupid example: take the union of a compact non-smoothable manifold with a noncompact manifold. 


Comment: I think Kervaire's example embeds into Euclidean space... maybe you could take a small open neighborhood (that deformation retracts back down to the original)? The obstruction is homotopy invariant, so that should do it.

Comment: A small open neighborhood of *anything* in the Euclidean space does admit a smooth structure:))

Comment: eek! what has happened to me? :P

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The Cairns-Hirsch theorem says that a PL manifold $M$ is smoothable if and only if $M\times \mathbb{R}$ is smoothable, so you can take $M$ to be any one of the known compact, PL examples such as Kervaire's manifold and then $M\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is non-smoothable for $n \geq 1$.

Comment: I wish to add for the benefit of the OP that any PL manifold $M$ is homotopy equivalent to a smooth manifold: properly embed $M$ into a a smooth $n$-manifold (e.g. Euclidean space) and take a regular neighborhood. I would be interested in any results on how (the smallest) $n$ depends on $M$.

Comment: @Igor: I think you have to be a little careful on how it's embedded, so that you can take a regular neighborhood which is homotopy equivalent. 

Comment: @Ian: the standard definition of a regular neighborhood of a subcomplex $K$ in a PL manifold is a closed neighborhood $R$ of $K$ that is a codimension zero PL submanifold, and that collapses to $K$ via finitely many elementary collapses. The last property implies that $R$ is simply homotopy equivalent to $K$.  

Comment: @Ian: perhaps the concern is that the embedding should be PL? Yes, I thought this is understood since we start from a PL manifold. We do not want wild embedding here, and any PL manifold has a PL embedding into a Euclidean space.